# Elasticsearch search fails in field with special character and wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I have a field in Elasticsearch with the value "PEI.H.02354.01.". When I search with `querystring` as

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "query_string":{  
         "query":"field:PEI.H.02354.01.",
         "default_operator":"AND"
      }
   }
}
```

then a result is returned, which is the correct behavior. But if I search with a wildcard, then no results are returned, e.g.

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "query_string":{  
         "query":"field:PEI.H.02354.01.*",
         "default_operator":"AND"
      }
   }
}
```

The field is of type string and analyzed. Below is the code that creates the index, including the analyzer and the mappings.

```
{
   "settings":{  
      "analysis":{  
         "analyzer":{  
            "number":{  
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"keyword",
               "filter":[  
                  "lowercase"
               ],
               "char_filter":[  
                  "number_filter"
               ]
            },
            "diacritical":{  
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"standard",
               "filter":[  
                  "standard",
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nfd_normalizer"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "nfd_normalizer":{  
               "type":"icu_normalizer",
               "name":"nfc"
            }
         },
         "char_filter":{  
            "number_filter":{  
               "type":"pattern_replace",
               "pattern":"[^\\d]+",
               "replacement":""
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "testType":{  
         "_source":{  
            "enabled":false
         },
         "_all":{  
            "enabled":false
         },
         "_timestamp":{  
            "enabled":"true",
            "store":"yes"
         },
         "properties":{  
            "field":{  
               "store":"yes",
               "type":"string",
               "index":"analyzed",
               "analyzer":"diacritical"
            }
         }
     }    
}
```

Finally, a sample insert is

```
{
    field: "PEI.H.02354.01."
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [query_string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) documentation:

Wildcarded terms are not analyzed by default — they are lowercased (lowercase_expanded_terms defaults to true) but no further analysis is done

your stored data is broken up into two terms:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/_analyze?analyzer=diacritical&pretty' -d 'PEI.H.02354.01'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "pei.h",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 5,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "02354.01",
    "start_offset" : 6,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "<NUM>",
    "position" : 2
  } ]
}
```

but as your search term with a wildcard is only turned into `pei.h.02354.01.*` it won't match.

however with `analyze_wildcard` set to **true**, you do get hits:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myindex/testType/_search?pretty" -d'
> {
>    "query":{
>       "query_string":{
>          "query":"field:PEI.H.02354.01.*",
>          "default_operator":"AND",
>          "analyze_wildcard": true
>       }
>    }
> }'
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.4142135,
```

Comment: Using this indeed returns results, but not all of them are correct, e.g. I also get PEI.H.4545.01. This makes sense if, as you said, the search term is analysed and basically what ES searches for is pei.h OR 02354.01. But is there a way to avoid this and search for PEI.H.02354.01. as a total, instead of breaking it in two terms?

Comment: It sounds like you want to treat PEI.H.02354.01 as a single string - if  so you need to change your analyzer, e.g. to tokenise on spaces only.

Comment: Possibly for this kind of searching you should use a multi-field with a different analyser.

Comment: I replaced standard tokenizer with whitespace tokenizer and this way the behavior is correct, i.e. punctuation is not tokenized.